# html template with echo php

Tags: php, html

I make a html template, a presentation page. Its ok (estetic) if I use `<?php echo $text_name; ?>` to include my text from php in html pages?

Exemple

```
<div class="col-four">
    <ul>
        <h1><?php echo $footer_colone_title; ?></h1><br>
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content1; ?></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content2; ?></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content3; ?></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content4; ?></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content5; ?></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content6; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Php

```
<?php
    $footer_colone_title = "Impachetari";
    $footer_colone_content1 = "Alge margine";
    $footer_colone_content2 = "Ceai verde";
    $footer_colone_content3 = "Ciocolata";
    $footer_colone_content4 = "Namol";
    $footer_colone_content5 = "Parafinaa";
    $footer_colone_content6 = "Argila albastra";
?>
```

and use function `<?php include("lang/ro.php"); ?>` ?

It's that ok or i may have problems if i do this?

Comment: You can only render `<?php ...` in `.php` files. So if you have anything like `<?php` within a `.html` file it will just show the code.

Comment: it works. but i just wanted to know if it's estetic ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, It is perfectly fine..

```
<div class="col-four">
            <ul>
                <h1><?php echo $footer_colone_title; ?></h1><br>
                <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content1; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content2; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content3; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content4; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content5; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><?php echo $footer_colone_content6; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Its really a basic one. so no need to confuse